# Model loading fails with Assimp via LWJGL bindings

Tags: java, lwjgl, assimp

Im trying to import Collada (.dae) files using the Assimp bindings present in LWJGL 3. It happens like this:

```
    InputStream = Class.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
    byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(getInputStream());

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(bytes.length + 1);
    byteBuffer.put(bytes);
    byteBuffer.put((byte) 0);
    byteBuffer.flip();

    AIScene scene;
    try {
        scene = Assimp.aiImportFile(byteBuffer, Assimp.aiProcess_Triangulate);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However, `scene` always turns out as `null`. (`IOUtils` is from apache-commons-io, `BufferUtils` is from lwjgl.)

I added the `byteBuffer.put(0)` part because without it, the Assimp call would always terminate throwing an exception saying that the bytebuffer isn't null-terminated. I've also tried many different files that work in other software. Is there a way to find out what exactly failed when loading the model?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to use the function `aiImportFileFromMemory` instead, the `aiImportFile` method is for loading directly from a file.